# Event Log track Module issue

Tags: sql-server, nginx, module, drupal-8

I am working with Drupal 8.9.11 and Microsoft-SQL and Nginx

I installed the Event Log track Module using composer
this module has many Sub-Modules like Event Log track File, Event Log track User Authentication, Event Log track user, Event Log track menu Etc.
I was able to enable the Event Track module but after enabling the sub-module Event Log track User Authentication the issue happens.

Then when I logged in as unprivileged user then error shows.

Its same with same with all other sub-modules whenever a sub-module is enabled the page shows error

> 10504#9164: *438 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: "SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'lid', table 'ltts.dbo.event_log_track'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails." at C:\nginx\html\ltts\drivers\lib\Drupal\Driver\Database\sqlsrv\Connection.php line 573" while reading response header from upstream>

I searched the error in the web but no result. What is the issue? Can anyone help?

Comment: Guess the install failed...

Comment: The installation did not fail I did it with composer.

Comment: No one said the installation failed. An update statement attempted by YOUR APPLICATION failed as the error indicates. You will need to debug the code - or find the documentation (or some guide) to understand how to configure and enable this functionality. Try posting your question on the drupal forums.